# JSON serialization with relation and @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have two classes:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
public class Client extends AbstractEntity {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();
```

And:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
 public class Patient extends AbstractLastOpenedDateEntity implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Client client;
```

Let say that I have a patient list:
-patient A (from client 1)
-patient B (from client 1)
-patient C (from client 2)
What I would like when I serialize it using Jackson:

```
[
   { id: A, client: { id: 1, patients: [A,B]}  },
   { id: B, client: { id: 1, patients: [A,B]}  },
   { id: C, client: { id: 2, patients: [C]}  },
]
```

But here is what I get:

```
[
   { id: A, client: { id: 1, patients: [ A , { id: B, client: { id: 1, patients: [A,B]}]}  },
   B,
   { id: C, client: { id: 2, patients: [C]}  },
]
```

It seems that Jackson do a "full serialization" only the first time and then it do a "short serialization" (id). 
What I would like to have to have full serialization with priorities for "root" json level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) annotation in your patients Set.
The problem is that @JsonIdentityInfo will full serialize only one 
occurrence of a object in the entire serialization process by default.